# Paho mqtt client not working properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, mqtt, paho

I'm new to MQTT and raspberry pi! I'm running a client script and I simply publish a message using another script. I'm using my own Mosquitto broker.

Client:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))

    client.subscribe("Example/test")
    client.subscribe("Example/topic")


def on_message(client, userdata, msg):

    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))


    if msg.payload == "Hello":
        print("Received message #1, do something")

    if msg.payload == "World":
        print("Received message #2, do something else")


client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.connect("192.168.1.4", 1883)


client.loop_forever()
```

Publisher:

```
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish


publish.single("Example/test", "Hello", hostname="192.168.1.4")
publish.single("Example/topic", "World", hostname="192.168.1.4")

print("OK")
```

That's where things seem weird and those things happen.
1.When I run both the client and the publisher using the python3 command the if statements are skipped and only topic + payload are printed
2.When I run the client using python command and publisher using both python3 and python command everything works fine!
3.When I do all the above, while running the client on virtualenv again the if statements are ignored, in all occasions!

I would like to know if there is a compatibility reason for this to happen, or anything wrong in the code as I must run something more complicated like that on virtualenv!

---

UPDATE: I found a solution that works fine ! 
In the client code in the if statement I used

```
if msg.payload == b"Hello":
```

and

```
if msg.payload == b"World":
```

As far as I know it must have been due to a variable type thing and they  didn't match.

Comment: Rather than edit the question to add the solution, you can use the answer and mark it as accepted then it's easier to find (and you event get a badge for answering your own question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution that works fine ! 
In the client code in the if statement I used

```
if msg.payload == b"Hello":
```

and

```
if msg.payload == b"World":
```

As far as I know it must have been due to a variable type thing and they  didn't match.

Answer (score 1):

stumbled upon this post while trying Paho mqtt client -

It may be good to note how characters & bytes are treated in Python, as explained in detail in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6273618/4149861) post.

So, above snippet could also be written as,

```
if (msg.payload.decode() == 'Hello'):
```